# How to blit from the x and y coordinates of an image in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to lessen the number of files I need for my pygame project by instead of having a folder with for example 8 boots files, I can make 1 bigger image that has all of them 8 pictures put next to each other and depending on animation tick, that specific part of the image gets blitted.

Currently, I utilise lists.

```
right = ["playerdesigns/playerright0.png","playerdesigns/playerright1.png","playerdesigns/playerright2.png","playerdesigns/playerright3.png"]
```

my code then just depending on animation tick, takes on of those files and blits it

but I wish to make it into one **playerright.png** image file that 0-100 Xpixels of the picture has **playerright1.png**, 101-200 Xpixels has **playerright2.png** etc, and then depending on need, I can blit 100 wide image from any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a subsurface that is directly linked to the source surface with the method [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface):

> `subsurface(Rect) -> Surface`
>
> Returns a new Surface that shares its pixels with its new parent. The new Surface is considered a child of the original. Modifications to either Surface pixels will effect each other.

The `Rect` argument of `subsurface` specifies the rectangular area for the sub-image. It can either be a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object or a tuple with 4 components (*x*, *y*, *width*, *height*).

For example, if you have an image that contains 3 100x100 size sub-images:

```py
right_surf = pygame.image.load("playerdesigns/playerright.png")
right_surf_list = [right_surf.subsurface((i*100, 0, 100, 100)) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are right_surf.subsurface 3rd and 4th parameters how big the image is (Width and Height)?

Comment: @Kuiu Yes. I've add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Made some testing with that and seems to work like intended, huge thanks