# pygame - surface from part of another surface

Tags: python, pygame

how can I create a surface from a section of another surface.  Reason is that I have an image as a background, and on that am displaying a clock - so when i update a new time, I need to first restore the original background back on that section before bliting the new clock text. I could do this using flip / full screen update, but want to avoid that and only update / restore a section of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a section of the screen by passing a a single rectnagle or a list of rectangles to [`pygame.display.update`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update):

> Update portions of the screen for software displays. [...] You can pass the function a single rectangle, or a sequence of rectangles.

e.g.:

```py
pygame.display.update(rect_region)
```

You can define a subsurface that is directly linked to the source surface with the [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) method:

> Returns a new Surface that shares its pixels with its new parent. The new Surface is considered a child of the original. Modifications to either Surface pixels will effect each other.

e.g.:

```py
rect_region = (x, y, width, height)
subsurf = source_surf.subsurface(rect_region)
```

Alternatively the [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method allows to specify a rectangular sub-area of a source *Surface*:

> [...] An optional area rectangle can be passed as well. This represents a smaller portion of the source Surface to draw. [...]

e.g.:

```py
rect_region = (x, y, width, height)
traget.blit(source_surf, (posx, posy), rect_region)
```

See also [How can I crop an image with Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239769/how-can-i-crop-an-image-with-pygame/65627793#65627793) and [Pygame - blitting from x and y cordinates of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828379/pygame-blitting-from-x-and-y-cordinates-of-image/65828456#65828456).